# IE 8 Rounded Corners Issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css3pie

I have been struggling with IE8 issue's and came across this issue of Rounded corners , 
Where all the browsers would accept border-radius except IE8.

```
font-size: 12px;
margin-left: 7px;
margin-top: -13px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px / 5px 10px 5px 10px;
```

Answer (score 2):

After a long struggle i have resolved this issue,

Downloaded : http://css3pie.com/

Used it in CSS as below:

font-size: 12px;

```
enter code here
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px; /* Chrome */
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;
     border-radius: 5px; /* CSS3 */
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; /* Mozilla */
     behavior: url(http://dev.intervalorders.com/pie/PIE.php);
```

Answer (score 1):

`border-radius` isn't supported by IE8: http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius

Answer (score 0):

**Internet explorer does not support border-radius**. But you can achieve it by implementing some hacks. Check this [link](http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers) for help.

Comment: Not really true. IE9+ supports border-radius.

Comment: yup.. IE 9 has supports CSS3. sorry, i forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

Why everyone wrote "border-radius isn´t support in IE or in IE8" etc..? IE9 support border-radius and lower version of IE support border-radius with PIE and this theme is about PIE not about default support border-radius in IE8 or older.

---

And answer on question:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px; // simply "6px" is ok too as in another CSS function
-moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px; // simply "6px" is ok too as in another CSS function
border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px; // simply "6px" is ok too as in another CSS function
behavior: url(funkce/PIE.php); //change link on your local folder where you have PIE.php (in this file is include PIE.htc that alow you use PIE without change .htacces file. For that you must have PIE.php file and PIE.htc file too.)
```